# How to catch errors thrown by logging library itself in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, logging, python-logging

I accidentally called logging.info() in a wrong way using Python3, and the library itself threw an error to the console, but the FileHandler failed to catch such error. So is there a way to catch all the errors no matter where they are thrown.

The error message looks like:

```
--- Logging error ---
...
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "<ipython-input-12-5ba547bc4aeb>", line 1, in <module>
    logging.info(1,1)
Message: 1
Arguments: (1,)
```

Copying the following code can reproduce my question. The log file can catch logging.info() and the error of ZeroDivisionError, but it failed to catch error messages thrown by the logging library.

```
import logging

logger_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

logger_handler = logging.FileHandler('/Users/your_name/Desktop/logging.log')

logger_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
root_logger.addHandler(logger_handler)

try:
    logging.info('test')
    logging.info(1,1)
    1/0
except:
    logging.exception("")
```

Log file output:

```
2021-03-10 18:07:32,315 - root - INFO: test
2021-03-10 18:07:32,324 - root - ERROR: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-6a4f609a80ca>", line 17, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging all errors that can happen during logging is impossible, because the error may be such that it breaks logging and if that would trigger a logging call it would lead to an infinite loop. You can however implement custom error handling by overriding `handleError` for your Handlers, and if you are feeling particularly brave, attempt to write a log within that error handler. Based on your code it would look something like this:

```
import logging

class MyFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def handleError(self, record):
        logging.error('There was an error when writing a log. Msg was: '+str(record.msg))

logger_handler = MyFileHandler('custom.log')
logger_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
root_logger.addHandler(logger_handler)

try:
    logging.info('test')
    logging.info(1,1)
    1/0
except:
    logging.exception("")
```

Of course if you would rather have an exception that bubbles up instead you could just raise from `handleError`.

Comment: Thank you @blues. In case someone is interested in the source code of `handleError` method, take a look from here:https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/531f2ebd60a662111c78107935d249d3d52f9a4f/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L985